# Error involving the identifier R (when embedding a project inside another)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an android project that involves a parent project (A) that calls another android project (B). I have added project B into A as a module and set the dependency. However, after adding project B into project A, ALL Java files in the added project B show an error at the line involving the symbol R (e.g. setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection);).

The error printed is "error: constant expression required."

I have searched a lot online but most answers deal with situations in which R.something.something occurs in a switch/case statement (not the case here). I have also verified that my package name in Project B files is exactly the same as that in Project B Manifest. I have also tried clean/build.

Note that project B runs fine when run individually (without integrating it in project A). Its only when I include it in project A do I run into these errors. In addition, my method of including the project as a module seems to be fine because I have applied the same approach on project C and it works fine inside project A.

I am a complete beginner to android. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you did the dependencies properly:

1) In the settings.gradle file:

```
include ':app', ':projectB', ':projectC'
```

2) In the build.gradle (Module: app):

```
compile project(':projectB')
compile project(':projectC')
```

3) If projectB uses any external library added to its libs folder, you should also add it to the main projects libs folder (but this is not the problem in your case).

Comment: The problem was a bit different. Strangely, Android Studio issued errors on every occurrence of R. However, when I got the ones in switch/case replaced with if/else, all errors disappeared, even the ones not in switch/case statement.

Comment: This problem happens a lot for some reason. Most of the time cleaning/rebuilding/restarting solves the problem, but sometimes you may end up reinstalling android studio